# If 12x ≡ 1 mod 85, find x?

Tags: number-theory

I found x = 78 by brute force but I want to use some very basic Elementary Number Theory proofs to find the answer to this. I am stumped, please help me. I'm going crazy.

Comment: $85 = 7\cdot 12 + 1$, thus $7\cdot12x \equiv -x \equiv 7 \pmod{85}$, so $x\equiv -7\pmod{85}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, upon dividing $85$ by $12$, we see that

$$85 = 7 \cdot 12 + 1$$

Rearranging a bit,

$$85 - 7 \cdot 12 = 1$$

Reducing modulo $85$, we then have

$$(-7) \cdot 12 \equiv 1 \pmod{85}$$

So $x \equiv -7 \equiv 78 \pmod{85}$.

---

More generally, an application of the extended Euclidean algorithm can solve these congruences.

Comment: Would it matter what the 'b' in the equation a ≡ b mod n is? Like say the original question was If 12x ≡ 10 mod 85, find x? wouldn't we arrive at the same conclusion?

Comment: @stumpy Once you solve $12 x \equiv 1$, just multiply $x$ by $10$ to get the new solution.

Comment: So the new solution would be 780?

Comment: @stumpy Yes, which can be reduced modulo $85$.

Comment: So say we have 17x ≡ 1 mod 19, find x. So then 19 = 1*17 +2, 19-1*17=2, -1*17≡1 (mod 19) so x≡-1≡18 (mod 19). I don't think I'm getting this right because if x=18 then 17*18=306 which is not ≡ 1 mod 19. What am I doing wrong here? Or is this just an example that doesn't "work"?

Answer (score 1):

$12x \cong 1 \mod 85 \Longrightarrow$

$(12*7)^2 \cong 1 \mod 85 \Longrightarrow$

$144*49 \cong 1 \mod 85 \Longrightarrow$

$12*(49*12) \cong 1 \mod 85 \Longrightarrow$

$588 \mod 85 \cong ((85*6) + \mathbf{78}) \mod 85$